# How can I implement a Breadth first search of a graph using Java?

Tags: java, graph, linked-list, hashmap, breadth-first-search

I need to do this using a text file which contains a linked list  of the graph which would be,
 (AEDB),
  (EA),
 (DA),
(BAC), 
 (CB), 
Then I ask the user for the node to start at and then the BFS order prints?
I know one way to start would be to create a linked list then hash the linked list in a dictionary but don't know from there on, also a node can't be visited more than once. My linked list is something like,
            HashMap> L = new HashMap>();

```
    LinkedList<String> listA = new LinkedList<String>();
    listA.add("B"); 
    listA.add("E");

    L.put("A", listA);

    LinkedList<String> listB = new LinkedList<String>();
    listB.add("A");
    listB.add("C");
    listB.add("F");

    L.put("B", listB);

    LinkedList<String> listE = new LinkedList<String>();
    listE.add("A");
    listE.add("F");

    L.put("E", listE);

    LinkedList<String> listF = new LinkedList<String>();
    listF.add("E");
    listF.add("K");
    listF.add("B");

    L.put("F", listF);

    LinkedList<String> listK = new LinkedList<String>();
    listK.add("F");
    listK.add("C");

    L.put("K", listK);

    LinkedList<String> listC = new LinkedList<String>();
    listC.add("K");
    listC.add("B");

    L.put("C", listC);
```

The output would print the nodes starting from the user inputted one in a breadth first order, but this is as far as I have gotten

Comment: I have created a linked list of the nodes

Comment: do you have to read from files? can you read from all the files once and store in a data structure like a class? and why are there multiple files?

Comment: @SkullFace Post your code ! Tell us what output you expect and what what you get.

Answer (score 3):

What you have used here is called an [Adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

Here is an implementation of BFS which uses an `adjacency list` like the one you have mentioned above and does a BFS. It prints the visited vertices in a BFS traversal.

```
public static void BFS(HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> adjLst, String start) {
    Queue<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    HashSet<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
    queue.add(start);
    while(0 != queue.size()){
        String vertex = queue.poll();
        if(!seen.contains(vertex)){
            System.out.print(vertex + " ");
            queue.addAll(adjLst.get(vertex)); // Add all neighbors of 'vertex' to the queue
            seen.add(vertex);
        }
    }
}
```